# delete ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models

how do you delete a ManyToMany relationship in django. how will youu remove m2m then delete the foto this is my models below thanks

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,blank = True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank = True, null = True)

class Land(Properies):
    photo = models.ManyToManyField(Picture,blank=True,related_name='Land_Pictures',null = True)
```

i have tried to delete it this way

```
checked_list = []
start = 1            
land_photos = sorted(list(land.photo.select_related()),reverse =True)
while start < 8:
    photo = 'photo%s' % start
    checked = form.cleaned_data[photo]
    if checked != None:
        checked_list.append(land_photos[start - 1])
        start += 1            
for a_foto in checked_list:
     land.photo.remove(a_foto)
     try:
         a_foto.remove_all_file()
         a_foto.delete()
     except OSError:
         pass
```

and then i get an error like this

```
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    
Picture object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

Comment: what do you mean with "delete"? deleting related records or remove completely the relationship?

Comment: how will youu remove m2m then delete the foto this is my models below thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
>>> land.photo.remove(some_picture)
```

Or the other way around, using the provided `related_name` argument:

```
>>> picture.Land_Pictures.remove(some_land)
```

By default, without `related_name`, it would be:

```
>>> picture.land_set.remove(some_land)
```

Comment: yes this removes the it but how do i den delet the photo it self i get a kinds of integrity error the the foto and the land gets deleted

Comment: here is the error Picture object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.

Comment: i tried it like this checked_list = []
start = 1            
land_photos = sorted(list(land.photo.select_related()),reverse =True)
while start < 8:
    photo = 'photo%s' % start
    checked = form.cleaned_data[photo]
    if checked != None:
        checked_list.append(land_photos[start - 1])
        start += 1            
for a_foto in checked_list:
land.photo.remove(a_foto)
try:
    a_foto.remove_all_file()
    a_foto.delete()
except OSError:
    pass

Comment: God this is awefully hard to read. Could you update your topic please ? Thanks, like we say, "Help me help you" :)

Comment: hi @ i have updated the question for a while now and i have not heard from you kindly help me look in to it thanks

Comment: Yeah the updated question doesn't inspire me so much. Apparently you're trying to remove models that haven't yet been saved. You haven't posted the stacktrace, but assuming that `land.photo.remove(a_foto)` raises the exception, you could fix it by wrapping that in `if a_foto.pk:`